# When a form disposed, are all form data and datasets also disposed?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

As the title, When a form disposed, are all `form` data and `datasets` also disposed?

Example:

```
Dim C As New Commands
C.ShowDialog
C.Disopse()
```

So `C` form contains `datasets` and `oledbconnections` and more objects that were not disposed . If not, what is the best method to free memory and release all resources?

Comment: There is no "best method" to free memory.  You release resources with a Using statement or by disposing them in, say, the FormClosed event.

Comment: Thank you , but what about the objects declared in form functions and subs , is it also be disposed with form ?

Comment: No.  If you never heard about the Using statement before then be sure to pick up an introductory book about vb.net programming.  It matters.

Answer (score 0):

As with other .NET objects, you cannot guarantee datasets will be disposed when the form is disposed. This is because .NET constantly monitors whether or not there are active pointers to the objects in memory. If no links were found, it frees up memory allocated to the object. Such process is called [garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) - a feature of CLR.

Problem is that you can have a variable that points to the same data set, on another form, class, and even in another project. You can spawn as many of those variables as you want. As a developer, you must work out a strategy to control who consumes your objects and how. Otherwise you will never know if at any given moment a particular dataset was actually disposed.

[Using clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) helps control disposal of objects, but it's not the ultimate solution. You can still get in trouble if you don't know what you are doing. And sometimes you would need to pass undisposed connection objects to other functions on purpose, for more granular control over data processing.

Answer (score 0):

A form's .Dispose() method is there to handle the otherwise-unmanaged GDI resources used by the form. Since that method doesn't know anything else about what you might have added, you can't be sure that items such as datasets are disposed as well.

The best you can hope for is that since Dispose()-ing a form is also highly indicative that the form is about to become eligible for garbage collection, your other resources are also likely about to become eligible for garbage collection. *If* the Dispose() and finalizer patterns for those types was implemented correctly, then it is *highly likely* that your other items will be disposed soon. Just how soon is impossible to say... that's why the dispose pattern exists: for those times when you need to sure an unmanaged resource is cleaned up right away.

The way I would recommend freeing any additional resources is to *override* the normal Windows Forms Dispose() method. Your new implementation of the Dispose() method will call the base implementation using the MyBase keyword, and also call Dispose() for any IDisposable members of your form. This way, the form will still work correctly as part of a Using block.